# Subprocess.run memory of variables

Tags: python, subprocess

Suppose we have the following:

```
import subprocess
import sys
a = 6
result = subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-c", "a*2"])
```

Why does it say `a` is not defined? Does the `subprocess` module remember prior variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess` created a new python process, as though you opened up a new terminal and ran `python` there. The new process does not share any memory, and certainly does not have access to the global variable dictionary of the current process.

You can expand the value of `a` directly in the string:

```
subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-c", f"print({a} * 2)"])
```

Alternatively, you can pass in the value of `a` by setting it in a separate statement:

```
subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-c", f"a = {a}; a * 2"])
```

In all cases, you need to print the result if you want to see console output.

If you want to use something other than numbers, use `{a!r}` in preference to just `{a}`, since `repr` is more likely to create a string that can be interpreted back to the original object.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Can this work with dataframe objects?

Comment: @stackguy1723. For dataframes, you have a bunch of options. You can make a code representation, read from a file, or even use alternatives like reading from clipboard. If you wanted to do this with dataframes, you should have asked about dataframes.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244435/discussion-on-answer-by-mad-physicist-subprocess-run-memory-of-variables).